# node Net.socket - remote end sends FIN; socket stuck in LAST_ACK

Tags: node.js, sockets

Using node js, I'm polling a remote connection every 60s and reusing existing open sockets when possible, reconnecting otherwise.

The remote end often closes the socket after 50s (sends a FIN i assume) and I handle the `end` event with a `socket.close()` or `socket.destroy()`. In both cases `ss -tan` shows that the socket goes from `ESTAB` -> `LAST-ACK` with a `Send-Q` of 1.

The upcoming polling hit 10s later seems to suffer from the connection being in this state when a reconnect is attempted. The reconnection takes 7.2s instead of the usual 200ms.

Is there a way to close the socket faster so that the reconnects happen as fast as fresh connections? Do i need to tweak the socket handling at the system level? Is it normal for LAST-ACK to take this long?

This is running on Debian testing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reconnect is not affected by the existence of prior connections, unless you run out of local outbound ports at the client. It doesn't cause a delay. LAST_ACK means you have received a FIN, sent an ACK, sent a FIN, and are waiting for the reply ACK. There is nothing either application can do at this point: the sockets are closed and it's all in the hands of TCP.

Comment: so i ran tcpdump to see what was going on and it looks like the remote end is not sending the final reply ACK and my end is trying a few retransmissions. At 66s the remote end sends an RST and the (re)connection attempt that at this point are retransmitting SYN packets to the other end get a reply and reconnect. There are plenty of resources avail on both ends, so that limbo socket is def affecting the reconnect.